# How many qdiscs can I create with tc?

Tags: iptables, network-interface, tc

I am trying to emulate traffic among multiple virtual machines. Each connection is supposed to have different parameters, i.e. delay. Therefore, I am trying to create different qdisc filters for different links because this way I can easily append a delay to each qdisc. Only I realised I cannot add more than 16 qdiscs with tc.
Is there a way to add more than 16 qdiscs? Can I maybe create another handle, handle 2?

Moreover, my commands do not work for the 10th qdisc I am adding: the connection with handle 10 (192.168.0.105 to 192.168.0.102). This connection appears to use qdisc rule with handle 20 since I measure a delay slightly above 30ms.

Here are the commands executed in the bash:

```
/sbin/tc  qdisc add dev eth1 root handle 1: prio bands 11  
/sbin/tc  qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:1 handle 10: netem  delay 200ms
/sbin/tc  qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:2 handle 20: netem  delay 30ms
/sbin/tc  qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:3 handle 30: netem  delay 300ms
/sbin/tc  qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:4 handle 40: netem  delay 70ms
/sbin/tc  qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:5 handle 50: netem  delay 80ms
/sbin/tc  qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:6 handle 60: netem  delay 90ms
/sbin/tc  qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:7 handle 70: netem  delay 110ms
/sbin/tc  qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:8 handle 80: netem  delay 400ms
/sbin/tc  qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:9 handle 90: netem  delay 110ms
/sbin/tc  qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:a handle 100: netem  delay 250ms

/sbin/tc  filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32  match ip dst 192.168.0.101/32 match ip src 192.168.0.102/32 flowid 10:1
/sbin/tc  filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 2 u32  match ip dst 192.168.0.101/32 match ip src 192.168.0.103/32 flowid 20:2
/sbin/tc  filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 3 u32  match ip dst 192.168.0.101/32 match ip src 192.168.0.104/32 flowid 30:3
/sbin/tc  filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 4 u32  match ip dst 192.168.0.101/32 match ip src 192.168.0.105/32 flowid 40:4
/sbin/tc  filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 5 u32  match ip dst 192.168.0.101/32 match ip src 192.168.0.106/32 flowid 50:5
/sbin/tc  filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 6 u32  match ip dst 192.168.0.101/32 match ip src 192.168.0.108/32 flowid 60:6
/sbin/tc  filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 7 u32  match ip dst 192.168.0.101/32 match ip src 192.168.0.109/32 flowid 70:7
/sbin/tc  filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 8 u32  match ip dst 192.168.0.102/32 match ip src 192.168.0.103/32 flowid 80:8
/sbin/tc  filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 9 u32  match ip dst 192.168.0.102/32 match ip src 192.168.0.104/32 flowid 90:9
/sbin/tc  filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio a u32  match ip dst 192.168.0.102/32 match ip src 192.168.0.105/32 flowid 100:a
/sbin/tc  qdisc add dev eth1 parent 1:b handle 110:  pfifo
/sbin/tc  filter add dev eth1 protocol ip parent 1:0 prio b u32 match ip src 0.0.0.0/0 match ip dst 0.0.0.0/0 flowid 110:b
```

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but I ran into the same issue and I solved it by using htb and tc classes.

Try this:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb

tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100mbit
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 1 u32 flowid 1:1 match ip dst 192.168.0.101/32 match ip src 192.168.0.102/32
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 10: netem delay 200ms

tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:2 htb rate 100mbit
tc filter add dev eth0 parent 1: protocol ip prio 2 u32 flowid 1:2 match ip dst 192.168.0.101/32 match ip src 192.168.0.103/32
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:2 handle 20: netem delay 30ms
```

and so on...

I believe this will allow you to create 9,999 different rules, though I have never tried that many myself.

I hope this helps!